# Is it not possible to perform non-linear filtering in frequency domain?

Tags: image-processing, filtering

[This link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/filtops.htm) contains the following statement:

> In contrast to the frequency domain, it is possible to implement non-linear filters in the spatial domain. In this case, the summations in the convolution function are replaced with some kind of non-linear operator.

Why is it not possible to perform non-linear filtering in frequency domain ?

Comment: You *could*, by adding spectral components in just the right amounts, but it would be far more complicated than just doing it in the time domain.  Likewise, non-linear frequency processing is much easier to do in the frequency domain than the time domain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linear filters in the spatial domain have a direct equivalent in the frequency domain, so you can transform your data and filter between spatial<->frequency domains and get equivalent results. However the transforms that we use for converting between spatial<->frequency domains are only valid for *linear systems* - a non-linear filter such as a median filter therefore has no frequency domain equivalent, so we can't perform e.g. median filtering in the frequency domain.

Note that this does not mean that there are no non-linear operations that we can perform in the frequency domain, e.g. we could reduce all frequency components below a certain threshold value to zero, it's just that there are no counterparts between the two domains for non-linear operations, so the frequency domain threshold operation described would have no equivalent operation in the spatial domain.